# How long do jquery bindings take to set up?

Tags: jquery, performance, binding

I have a project that sets up several pages with articles. Each page has, at minimum three bindings: a sideways scroll, a vertical scroll and a titlebar you can pull down.

I also have a spinner, which stops when the script is done, but movement is slow for another few seconds.

I've seen many discussions of the speed for DOM traversal, but nothing for how long complicated bindings take to set up...

I would like to hide the spinner only when everything is ready, not when the code is run but stuff is still being arranged behind the scenes...

Comment: What do you mean by bindings and 'when everything is ready'?

Comment: please see my comment/response below. I was unable to add enough code to make it readable in a mere comment, but have linked to the github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings take very little time at all to setup. What may be taking up your time is the actual element selection before adding the bindings. If you're binding to lots of small elements (eg. every `<td>` in a table, or every `<p>` in the document), you might consider using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Comment: I am targeting very few small elements on the pages. One part of the script builds a table of contents and clones it to a static page and clones that to another page that is enabled by the pull-down menu. Those buttons then receive some binding love, which I guess could be done with delegate. 

The other part of the script relies on mouse/touch events to control the movement of items on the page. Should those be delegated?

The code is here, should you feel like taking a peek. https://github.com/nosarious/jscroll-slide-pull (It needs a serious review before making it widely available)